# Converting HtmlString to Int

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model, html-helper

I have a model with an attribute int. This attribute is a value that I need to count a forloop.

```
//Markup
@{var value = Html.DisplayFor(m => m.periodCounter).ToString();}
@for (var i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(value); i++)
{
//code here
}
```

I get the errormessage "Input string was not in a correct format". Is this possible to solve? All I really need to do is declaring a variable with the value of a textbox (in the same view). Right now I have a TextBoxFor and as you can see I'm trying to get and convert it with DisplayFor

Comment: What are you getting for `value`? If there are extra spaces, you might need to do a `.Trim()`

Comment: I think it is MvcHtmlString

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why are you converting a variable to HTML and then to an `int` again?

Comment: Tried with trim as well. The application crashes as soon as the view is loaded so I don't have the time to fill the model. Is that possible the issue?

Comment: @OscarPaz I'm having a textbox where the users should put in a value (int) and that value do I need to count a forloop in the same view

Comment: But your `value` variable does not have a textbox sent by the user. Are you storing it in `periodCounter`?

Comment: this doesn't make sense.  Your Model comes from you, not the user.  If you simply want to do an action with an `int` the user gives you, use a jquery function

Comment: @Jonesy but can I get the int from jquery to markup without writing for loop in js? The problem is that I want to use C# in markup for this

Comment: Are you trying to get it so that the user types a number, and then it runs the loop that many times (e.g. to show that many more text boxes)? To do this in C#, you'd **have to** post back (or otherwise recontact the server, e.g. via AJAX) so that the page can be completely reloaded. This is because the C# code isn't being executed at all on the client-side. The generally-better option would be to use jQuery, to build the elements *immediately* after the user types the number.

Answer (score 2):

Um...

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.periodCounter; i++)
```

?

Comment: The object is not created when the page loads (it's all in the same view). So I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Then your `Html.DisplayFor(...)`, method will fail, too.

Comment: @OscarPaz oh..of course. But is it suppose to be so hard to just give me a int value from textbox to a C# var in the same view?

Comment: @krillezzz depending on the timing you're thinking of, it could be completely impossible. Remember that the C# is server-side, and the only code you can run client-side is JS.

Comment: @TimS. I will rewrite everyting in jquery and try. Inside the loop I'm supposing to make a table and the code is (for me) much easier to write when mixing C# in markup instead of jquery